# Code not getting obfuscated with Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard

Im using proguard in my android studio. I have implemented Proguard in my **proguard-rules.pro** file. But after making a release apk the code is not getting obfuscated.

Here is the **proguard-rules.pro** file

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /home/chitra/Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-printmapping out.map
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,InnerClasses
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontoptimize
-repackageclasses ''
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.awt.**
-dontwarn com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.CommandInfo
-dontwarn com.google.zxing.**
-dontwarn com.actionsmicro.androidkit.ezcast.imp.googlecast.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.**
-dontwarn com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.server.MessageContext
-dontwarn com.actionsmicro.d.a.a
-dontwarn okio.Okio.**
-dontwarn okio.DeflaterSink.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn android.support.design.**

# The official support library.
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }

# The official design library.
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

# Keep fragments
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# EventBus 3.0
-keep class de.greenrobot.event.** { *; }
-keep interface de.greenrobot.event.** { *; }

-keep class com.** { *; }
-keep interface com.** { *; }

# crashlytics android
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.crashlytics.android.** { *; }

# digits sdk android
-keep class com.digits.sdk.** { *; }
-keep interface com.digits.sdk.** { *; }

# firebase, google services and gson
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.** { *; }

# square picasso
-keep class com.square.picasso.google.** { *; }
-keep interface com.square.picasso.** { *; }

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    !private <fields>;
    !private <methods>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Native Methods

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Android Support Library

-keep class android.** {*;}

# Button methods

-keepclassmembers class * {

public void *ButtonClicked(android.view.View);

}

# Reflection

-keepclassmembers class com.elsinga.sample.proguard.SensorDescriptionFragment {

public void updateFields(com.elsinga.sample.proguard.SensorData);

}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Remove Logging
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** wtf(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

What could be the problem for this? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely, you have excluded your own code in the rules.

So obfuscating is not run on your code.

I am unaware of your namespace, from your question, but the following lines would effect anything with `com.` at the start.

So if your namespace is `com.my.namespace` it will be excluded from obfuscation.

You should consider removing the following lines, or fully quantifying the namespaces it should be hiding, so as to not clash with your own.

```
-keep class com.** { *; }
-keep interface com.** { *; }
```

**update:**

You are also keeping all classes that extend Activity, Fragments etc. Which is most likely, every single page of code you have written.

```
# Keep fragments
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

There is unlikely to be a good reason for this. Try removing the above.

Comment: I have removed the code that you have mentioned. But still it is not working.

Comment: @Seenu69 Did you write the proguard file? or copy it from somewhere? Have you enabled it in the gradle build file? Do you use all those libraries it ignores, or is it all redundant code.

Comment: @Doomskinght I use all those libraries that I have mentioned in the proguard. Also I have enabled the proguard in build.gradle file also.

Comment: @Seenu69 See edit, it looks like you are also keeping all your activity and fragments from being obfuscated.

Comment: My package name starts with com.xxxx.xxxx. If i use -keep class com.** { *; } it is not obfuscating the actual code. How to resolve it?

Comment: @Seenu69 Delete the keep section.